# Less than operator giving weird results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have this query connecting a couple of tables together and returning data

```
SELECT * FROM userposts up
INNER JOIN userpostmeta upm
ON up.up_postID = upm.upm_postID
INNER JOIN userbasicprofile ubp
ON up.up_userID = ubp.ubp_userID
WHERE up.up_userID = :self OR up.up_userID IN (SELECT ufs_userID2 FROM userfriends where ufs_userID1 = :u)
AND
up.up_indexid < $startIndex AND up.up_indexid > 0
ORDER BY up.up_indexid DESC
LIMIT $limit
```

Table `userposts` has a column called 'up_indexid` which is **AUTO INCREMENT**

**The issue is**, when I send a value of `$startIndex` for support 31, it shows posts below `indexid` 31, but also shows posts above it.

Why is it happening? I've tried multiple breakpoints, but nothing seems to be solving it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason have nothing to do with `<`,it's caused by that you have `OR` in your mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM userposts up
INNER JOIN userpostmeta upm
ON up.up_postID = upm.upm_postID
INNER JOIN userbasicprofile ubp
ON up.up_userID = ubp.ubp_userID
WHERE up.up_userID = :self 
OR up.up_userID #OR makes things unexpected
  IN (SELECT ufs_userID2 FROM userfriends where ufs_userID1 = :u) 
AND
up.up_indexid < $startIndex AND up.up_indexid > 0
ORDER BY up.up_indexid DESC
LIMIT $limit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
'SELECT * FROM userposts up
INNER JOIN userpostmeta upm
ON up.up_postID = upm.upm_postID
INNER JOIN userbasicprofile ubp
ON up.up_userID = ubp.ubp_userID
WHERE up.up_userID = :self OR up.up_userID IN (SELECT ufs_userID2 FROM userfriends where ufs_userID1 = :u)
AND
up.up_indexid < ' . intval($startIndex) . ' AND up.up_indexid > 0
ORDER BY up.up_indexid DESC
LIMIT ' . intval($limit)
```

And i noticed you're using Binding and in-string variables, why not just bind the startIndex and limit too?
also, you might want to look at offsetting, might be a better solution in your case, like LIMIT 100, 10 (so 100 entries starting from the 10th entry)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html OR has lower priority than AND so your WHERE clause is interpreted as:

```
WHERE up.up_userID = :self OR (up.up_userID IN (SELECT ufs_userID2 FROM userfriends where ufs_userID1 = :u)
AND
up.up_indexid < $startIndex AND up.up_indexid > 0)
ORDER BY up.up_indexid DESC
LIMIT $limit
```

I guess what you want is the following:

```
WHERE (up.up_userID = :self OR up.up_userID IN (SELECT ufs_userID2 FROM userfriends where ufs_userID1 = :u))
AND
up.up_indexid < $startIndex AND up.up_indexid > 0
ORDER BY up.up_indexid DESC
LIMIT $limit
```